Select multiple column(Created Date) with duplicate unique ID in a single row
Having records like this



ID
Created Date




1
2024-07-23 00:25:17.113


1
2024-07-23 00:31:17.113


2
2024-07-23 00:22:17.113


2
2024-07-23 00:29:17.113



enter image description here
Expectation



ID
Created Date
Duplicate Date




1
2024-07-23 00:25:17.113
2024-07-23 00:31:17.113


2
2024-07-23 00:22:17.113
2024-07-23 00:29:17.113



enter image description here

This question is similar to: SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please do not use images for data, use formatted text. And please show us your query.

MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

it is weird to have a SQL database with repeated ID values. Also By doing this you assume that dates can only be repeated once, supposing that your table is named Records:
SELECT 
    r1.ID, 
    r1.Created_Date AS Created_Date, 
    r2.Created_Date AS Duplicate_Date
FROM 
    Records r1
JOIN 
    Records r2
ON 
    r1.ID = r2.ID 
AND 
    r1.Created_Date < r2.Created_Date;

If not, you only need to change the table name on the query example
